# C++ Vector Clone

Tags: c++, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel, memory-management, vectors

I'm learning C++, so I decided to make a simpler clone of `std::vector`.

Concerns:

- I have seen people defining methods outside of the class, and only prototyping them inside the class. Should I be doing this too?
- I'm new to lower-level languages that require memory management, so there might be leaks.
- Are there any performance optimizations I could make?
- Is my general style good?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template <class element>
class Vector {
  private:
  int len, cap;
  element* arr;

  void allocate_to_len() {
    int new_cap = min(cap, 1); // size-0 vectors wont loop infinitely
    while (len > new_cap) {
      new_cap *= 2;
    }
    resize(new_cap);
  }

  public:
  Vector() : Vector(10) {}

  Vector(int size) {
    len = 0;
    cap = size;
    arr = new element[size];
  }

  Vector(const Vector<element>& v) {
    len = v.length();
    cap = v.capac();
    arr = new element[cap];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      arr[i] = v.get_value(i);
    }
  }

  ~Vector() {
    delete[] arr;
  }

  element& operator[](int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= len) {
      throw "Index out of range";
    }
    return arr[index];
  }

  int length() const {
    return len;
  }

  int capac() const {
    return cap;
  }

  element get_value(int index) const {
    if (index < 0 || index >= len) {
      throw "Index out of range";
    }
    return arr[index];
  }

  void resize(int size) {
    cap = size;
    element* newarr = new element[size];
    len = std::min(len, cap);
    for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
      newarr[i] = arr[i];
    }
    arr = newarr;
  }

  void append(element item) {
    len += 1;
    allocate_to_len();
    arr[len - 1] = item;
  }

  void extend(Vector<element> d) {
    int length = d.length();
    int old_len = len;
    len += length;
    allocate_to_len();
    for (int i=0; i < length; i++) {
      arr[i + old_len] = d[i];
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  // Tests:

  Vector<int> d;

  d.append(1);
  d.append(2);
  d.append(3);

  for (int i=0; i<d.length(); i++) {
    std::cout << d[i] << "\n";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";

  Vector<int> d2;

  d2.append(4);
  d2.append(5);
  d2.append(6);

  d.extend(d2);

  for (int i = 0; i < d.length(); i++) {
    std::cout << d[i] << "\n";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";

  d.resize(4);

  for (int i = 0; i < d.length(); i++) {
    std::cout << d[i] << "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, lets answer the questions you have:

1. Yes, no, maybe. Some people do it one way, some the other. Personally, I prefer splitting declarations and definitions up so that I have an overview of what my class offers at the top. Some people argue, however, that this method tends to be very verbose (and it can be, especially with multi-layer templates), so either way is fine.
2. Yes, there is at least one memory leak in `resize()`. This is evident by the fact that you're allocating memory there, but not freeing the old memory. After the method returns, the internal pointer points to the newly allocated array while the old one is left abandoned and unreachable in the depths of the heap. To correct this, just `delete[]` the old array before you assign `arr = newarr`.
3. Probably, but I don't want to go into those here as

   - you do not seem to have measured any performance characteristics of the code, and as long as you don't benchmark you don't care about performance
   - this implies that you don't actually care too much about performance (if you did, you would have measured it) and
   - your code does not have anything that screams *"I'm going to be really slow"* at me, so there's little reason to optimize anyway.
4. Depends on what you mean by "general style". If you mean correct indentation, variable names etc. I'd say yes. If you mean use of the STL and standard algorithms, I'd say there's still work to do.

## Taking a closer Look

*You did not ask for this kind of review, so if you're not interested, feel free to simply ignore this part of the answer.*

While your overall code makes a pretty good impression on me, there are some things that don't look and feel right and, to my mind, deserve another thought or two:

1. While you say that your container is a simple clone of `std::vector`, its behavior differs gravely from the standard container when it comes to allocating and managing elements. The issue is that your container cannot reserve any memory without (default -) constructing elements. However, if you take a look at `std::vector`, you will find that it offers a `reserve` interface that lets you allocate memory in advance without actually constructing any elements. This kind of behavior is a little more difficult to realize in code, though, so you might want to stick with your current version if you're still in the process of getting a good hold of C++, especially if you don't feel safe working with low-level memory routines.
2. Although I tend to iterate on this point again and again, *int is not the right type for index and iteration variables*. First of all, it is a signed type, which allows it to take negative values (a fact which your dereference methods brace against). Secondly, on a modern x86_64 system (which happens to be what most desktop users are running), `int` is likely to only be a 32bit data type, which means that you are limiting yourself to about 4 gigabytes of memory for your vector, and running into the risks of overflows with high indices. Instead, C++ offers the type `std::size_t`, which lends itself very well to size- and index-variables, as the name suggests. It is unsigned, and, on a typical 64bit platform, is usually 64 bits in size.
3. It's a bad practice to force exceptions on users. One reason for this is that exceptions are really slow when they happen. Another reason is that exceptions are not readily available on all systems, especially not in the embedded development sector. My suggestion for you is to kind of follow the `std::vector` design pattern: Make `operator[]` unchecked and have undefined behavior on out-of-bounds access, and provide a `at()` method which does bounds checking and throws on out-of-bounds. This may also lead to increased performance, as the index validation can no be avoided if the index is known to be in bounds.
4. As I already mentioned in the answer to question four, there is some potential to use standard algorithms, in particular `std::copy` and `std::move` in places where you are copying/moving data from one array to another. In general, if you have a simple for loop over a range of elements that does nothing too complicated in its body, it is possible to replace the loop with a function call to something from `algorithm` or `numeric`.
5. Avoid magic numbers. For example, in `Vector() : Vector(10) {}`, what does the 10 mean? Why 10? Every time you find yourself writing a magic number, refactor it to a constant and give it a name. In this case, `vector_default_size` or something of the sort would be fitting.
6. Although this might partly be because this is a code review question, the interface your class offers is kind of meager. What I find especially lacking is support for iterators, i.e. `begin()` and `end()`. In the case of your vector, those would not be hard to implement at all, since every raw pointer automatically meets the requirements for a `RandomAccessIterator`.
7. Speaking of raw pointers, the way your class is currently implemented it lends itself very well to the use of `std::unique_ptr`. This will have the added benefit that you don't really need to worry about move constructor and destructor any more, because those will be automatically be taken care of by the unique pointer. In general, you should try to avoid raw pointers as much as possible, since they have no ownership semantics and are prone to mbe misused.

---

*Parts of this answer were written before Martin York posted his answer. Thus, there may be some points which overlap. If you find any of those points appealing, please give the credit to Martin York as he was faster than me.*

Comment: Point 2: I completely disagree with the `int is not the right type for index and iteration variables`. I think int is the better data type exactly because it can be negative. The trouble with unsigned types they auto convert negative values without so much as a hickup (and you end up with a very large positive value usally). By allowing negative values you can actually check for them and spot errors more easily.

Comment: Point 7: I disagree but not that much. I think smart pointers and containers are trying to achieve the same thing. Though i can see the argument for using a smart pointer as it simplifies the container, and this will work for very simple containers, but I believe that when you get down into the details of implementing the container those advantages disappear as the container is managing the memory for the container **and** all the elements in it.

Comment: Your answer is much more elegant and refined than mine. Thats why I was able to hammer out a response quickly.

Comment: @MartinYork Thanks for the praise! To address your points: Point 2: I guess there's two sides to the medal here. Even so, I don't think `int` is the right choice for indices and sizes because of its size limitations. If you prefer signed variables, `std::ptrdiff_t` would probably be the best choice, no? Point 7: In general, I agree with what you're saying. Maybe I didn't express this clearly enough, but I meant that the *current, very simple container implementation* would lend itself well to smart pointer usage since it's basically just managing a dynamic-size array.

Comment: Point 4: Unfortunately, there is no equivalent to `std::move_if_noexcept` in ranges terms, which is really annoying. Managing yourself the set of conditions is asking for troubles.

Comment: Point 7: Unfortunately, `std::unique_ptr` does not handle dynamically resizable arrays (it's what `std::vector` is for!). In this instance, you can still use it to handle the array memory itself (using `std::aligned_storage<>::type` for the element type), but you will still need to handle destruction yourself.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm not sure what you mean. There's `std::unique_ptr<type[]>` which handles dynamic arrays just fine. If you mean that the underlying memory is not resizable, well, that's obviously true. You can still use it to ensure automatic destructor calls etc., though, which is what I was proposing it for.

Comment: @BenSteffan: `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` requires the use of `new[]` which (1) will default construct all elements and (2) will destroy all elements upon destruction. Mandating that `T` be default constructible and wasting time default-constructing all `T` before overwriting them is NOT great :x

Comment: @MatthieuM. We were talking on the premise that the underlying semantics of the implementation are as-is, i.e. that there is no `resreve()` interface and default construction happens every time. If this were a correct `std::vector`-like implementation, then you would, of course, be right.

Comment: @BenSteffan: I was not :) I think that it is the purpose of codereview to challenge the OP's implementation after all; they may not even have realized this flaw.

Comment: @BenSteffan The whole "unsigned types for STL a big mistake" is pretty much the accepted consensus. [Even by the people who decided it back then](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything) (comes up repeatedly, first time around 12 minutes). It's a bug magnet and 99.99999% of all containers are fine with a 31bit size. For the teeny, tiny minority (that certainly exists, not arguing that) they might as well use their own special purpose container. Or more likely scale their computation by horizontally scaling.

Answer (score 29):

### Issues

Your vector assumes that the type being stored has a default constructor.

```
arr = new element[size];
```

Also this is really inefficient for expensive to create classes where you don't use all the `size` members. You want to design your class so that the objects in the vector are only constructed when the element is first added.

### Bug

You don't implement the rule of three.

By default the compiler creates three methods for you. Copy Constructor/Copy Assignment/Destructor. You have not implemented the Copy Assignment operator. This means you will have a bug (because of the shallow copy issue) if there is an assignment.

### Design Issue

Return values by reference:

```
element get_value(int index) const;
```

Here you return a copy of the element. This may be very expensive. So it would be nice if you return by reference (in this case const reference). This way you can read the data without actually making a copy of the data first.

### Design Issue

There is no point in checking index ranges when you can guarantee that the index is in bounds. You should design your class to allow expert users unfettered access (ie no checks) but also provided a checked interface for people still testing and using unvalidated input.

```
element& operator[](int index) {
  if (index < 0 || index >= len) {
    throw "Index out of range";
  }
  return arr[index];
}
```

This is the design used by `std::vector`.

```
T& std::vector::operator[](index);   // Does not check index
T& std::vector::at(index);           // Does check that index is valid
```

So in the case:

```
for(int loop = 0; loop < v.length(); ++loop) {
    std::cout << v[loop];
}
```

In this very standard situation I know that loop is always within the bounds. So doing a check on the bounds is not required. This is exactly why `std::vector<>` has two interfaces for accessing elements.

### Const Issues

A lot of interfaces pass object by `const reference`. This allows you to pass an object without copying it and without giving write access to the object (this is called const correctness).

As a result a lot of the accesses interfaces also have a const version.

```
T const& std::vector::operator[](index) const;   // Does not check index
T const& std::vector::at(index)         const;   // Does check that index is valid
```

### Memory Leak

```
  void resize(int size) {
    cap = size;
    element* newarr = new element[size];
    len = std::min(len, cap);
    for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
      newarr[i] = arr[i];
    }
```

Fix Here

```
    // before you can overwrite `arr`
    // You need to deallocate the array and all its members.
    std::swap(arr, newarr);  // So swap the values.
    delete [] newarr;        // Now you can delete the old array.
  }
```

### Notes

I wrote a series of articles about writing a vector.

[Vector - Resource Management](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/02/27/vector/)
[Vector - Copy and Swap](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/02/29/vector-resource-management-ii-copy-assignment/)
[Vector - Resize](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/03/12/vector-resize/)
[Vector - Simple Optimization](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/03/19/vector-simple-optimizations/)
[Vector - The other stuff](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/03/20/vector-the-other-stuff/)

Comment: Regarding bounds-checking: I do like using `assert` in `operator[]`, to help catch mistakes earlier...

Comment: "doing a check in the interface is gratuitously expensive". So how much do you figure the performance overhead is going to be in standard use cases? 20%? 15%? Or maybe more 0.1% if at all? And at what level of performance overhead is introducing security and correctness problems worth it?

Comment: @voo: I was being overly bombastic.

Comment: @Martin In my opinion introducing an extremely problematic security/correctness problem into an API in the name of performance (dubious at best, in the loop you use as an example, any good compiler should be able to remove the bounds checks) is certainly *not* best design or should be recommended. If it turns out that for the particular use case (auto vectorization? GPU code? Few examples spring to mind where this really matters) the bounds check causes troubles, sure include it, but in a default vector implementation? Very, very bad idea.

Comment: @voo If we look t the standard implementation of vector (`std::vecter`). You will see there are two interfaces. A checked interface and an unchecked interface. The reason for the difference is we don't want to restrict choice. For those that have done the appropriate validation we want to provide the optimal code, for those that that need to have runtime validation there is that option. Doing a quick test. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/03af79051d59bf3dce3ca366c1d66493 I see a difference in 0.35% (obviously simplistic test).

Comment: Updated wording to remove gratuitously and make it about the real reason. Design for efficiency but also protection.

Comment: @Martin Oh I know. There's always a tradeoff between simplicity and freedom in API design. For a standard container that has to work in many different situations providing a non-checked solution might be fine (although it's also fair to ask the tiny minority that need something like this to go with a specific, fine-tuned solution). But the choice of making the default non-checking was a big mistake and has lead to millions of exploits and errors for a negligent performance advantage. But we might have to disagree on that. On a positive note: Very good blog series.

Comment: @MartinYork Great post. 2 comments: 1. Why return by reference though when there is (N)RVO now? I very rarely return by reference, unless I'm going for function chaining. Also why return `const` reference? Will you be able to modify a `const&` afterwards? 2. "Your vector assumes that the type being stored has a default constructor." Well if we want to store an object to a container, we might as well make sure it has a default constructor! Any (container) class has to make just a couple of assumptions after all. No class can be that abstract to accept anything.

Comment: @Nik-Lz: 1) NRVO reduces the number of copies to one but it does not eliminate them. Returning by const reference eliminates all copies. For a container why have a copy at all if you don't need it.

Comment: @Nik-Lz 2 2) Sure you can make assumptions. But there is no need to make this one. Do I have to have a default (zero argument constructor) constructor to put things in `std::vector`. Why would your limit your class that way if you don't need to.

Comment: @Nik-Lz 1) Const reference.  Access functions (to a container) need two versions a normal version and const version. So the object can still be accessed (read) after it has been passed as a const reference to a function. Also symetry with the non cost version.

Comment: @Nik-Lz 1) Reference. Returning a reference to a member (non const version) allows you to update the value in place. `v[10] = 5;` Updates the value at location 10.

Answer (score 5):

I have not seen the other answers talk enough about how you manage vector sizes.

#### Design Issue

You are declaring `int len, cap;` but at least you are using `int` consistently. This would normally be using `size_t`. (see [Ben Steffan's answer](/a/187425/39791) point 2)

#### Implementation bug

`allocate_to_len` has a bug. Specifically, if `len > INT_MAX / 2`, you are overflowing `cap` which leads to undefined behaviour for `int` and overflow for `size_t`. The standard implementation of `vector` offers a method `max_size` that returns the largest implementation defined capacity. Reserving or increasing the vector beyond that size throws a `length_error`.

Similarly, in `append` you might overflow `len`.

#### Naming

`capac` should be called `capacity`. `get_value` is `at`. `length` is `size`. `append` is called `push_back` in C++. This leads me to my last point.

#### Adhere to the container concept

If you want your vector to be reusable in other contexts, you should adhere to the [container concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container). This would allow other libraries, e.g. `<algorithm>` to use your container.

Part of this would be to change `void extend(Vector<element> d)` (note also that you should be taking this argument by const reference) to `template <class InputIterator> void insert (iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);` aswell as implementing an `iterator` for your container.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments to the other answer, *signed types are fine here*, and are in fact the consensus of the committee nowadays. They concede that using unsigned types were a mistake, and, going forward, the standard will probably include a signed type `std::index_t` for indices and sizes.

Answer (score 5):

[**Exception Safety**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety)

Your container is not **exception safe**.

The first difficulty of writing a container in C++ is handling the memory when everything goes well. Other answers already address this point so I won't reiterate it.

The second difficulty of writing a container in C++ is handling the memory when the user is being adversarial. It is possible, in C++, to throw an exception:

- in a default constructor,
- in a copy constructor,
- in a copy assignment operator,
- in a move constructor,
- in a move assignment operator,
- in a destructor...

**Any time you invoke user logic, it may throw.**

You have to decide how to handle this behavior:

- Not accounting for exceptions is not an option, you can cop out by tagging your methods `noexcept`<sup>1</sup> though your users may not appreciate,
- At the very least, you should NOT leak (**Basic Exception Guarantee**); if you are using `new`/`delete` memory handling, you are more likely to fail this,
- You should always attempt to provide the **Strong Exception Guarantee**, which means that if the user-defined operation throws your container is left unmodified.

Note that the Strong Exception Guarantee would sometimes require expensive operations (copy and swap). In this case, it is better to stick to the Basic Exception Guarantee and document the behavior.

<sup>1</sup> *If an exception attempts to "leave" a `noexcept` method, the program terminates abruptly. It's better than corrupting memory, but still very annoying.*

---

With that in mind, please consider the following *start*:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    Vector() = default;

    //  WARNING:
    //  The COPY CONSTRUCTOR, COPY ASSIGNMENT OPERATOR and DESTRUCTOR
    //  are missing and should be defined. Correctly.

    void push_back(T&& e);
    void push_back(T const& e);

private:
    using Raw = typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>::type;

    void grow_by(std::ptrdiff_t n);

    T* raw();

    std::ptrdiff_t mCapacity = 0;
    std::ptrdiff_t mLength = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<Raw[]> mStorage;
};


template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::push_back(T&& e) {
    this->grow_by(1);

    new (this->raw() + mLength) T{std::move(e)};
    ++mLength;
}

template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::push_back(T const& e) {
    this->grow_by(1);

    new (this->raw() + mLength) T{e};
    ++mLength;
}

template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::grow_by(std::ptrdiff_t n) {
    if (mLength + n <= mCapacity) { return; }

    //  Prepare new storage
    auto newCapacity = std::max(mCapacity, 1);
    do {
        newCapacity *= 2;
    } while (mLength + n > newCapacity);

    Vector next;
    next.mCapacity = newCapacity;
    next.mStorage.reset(new Raw[newCapacity]);

    //  Transfer objects:
    //  1. if T's move constructor is noexcept, use it!
    //  2. otherwise, if T has a copy constructor, use it!
    //  3. otherwise, use T's move constructor.
    //
    //  Cases 1 and 2 offer the Strong Exception Guarantee; case 3
    //  unfortunately offers only the Basic Exception Guarantee.
    for (auto& t : *this) {
        next.push_back(std::move_if_noexcept(t));
    }

    //  "Commit" the change.
    std::swap(*this, next);
}

template <typename T>
T* Vector<T>::raw() { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(mStorage.get()); }
```

There are two `std` features of note here:

1. The use of `std::aligned_storage<>::type` gives us *raw* storage of suitable size and alignment: this obviates the need for default constructors of `T`!
2. The use of `std::move_if_noexcept` allows us to offer the best possible Exception Guarantee with little code.

Also, note how both `grow_by` and `push_back` are organized to provide the **Strong Exception Guarantee** (when possible):

1. Do the operations that may throw *without* modifying the object,
2. Commit the work.

In the case of `push_back`, you can see the length is only incremented if construction of the object is successful, for example.

In the case of `grow_by`, note how it reuses the current `Vector` class to handle the destruction of already copied/moved elements if an exception is thrown in the loop.

---

I will not lie, exception safety can be *hard* in vectors.

Inserting a *range* of elements in the *middle* of the vector is a nightmare when the move constructor/move assignment operator may throw.

Comment: I would change: `At best, you should provide` to `You should always attempt to provide (when acceptable)`,

Comment: Careful of overflow here: `newCapacity *= 2;`. This seems like a bug `mLength + n > newCapacity`

Comment: @MartinYork: There is indeed a risk of overflow, I'd rather not deal with it right here though as it is not the purpose of the sample. In a complete solution, I would advise against using the loop anyway; it's not bad (O(log N)), but there are more efficient ways of finding the next bigger power of 2 with intrinsics (`__builtin_clz` gives you  a leg up).

Comment: @MartinYork: I think `mLength + n > newCapacity` is right, any particular concern?

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to point out 2 more things that I saw that don't seem to have been mentioned yet.

**Append Resizes the Vector Every Time**

I see that you differentiate capacity and length. The general idea behind this is that the vector will always have some spare room to grow into without having to reallocate memory, copy elements, and de-allocate memory every single time. Within the `append` method you call `allocate_to_len()` regardless of whether or not more memory is needed. You should only call `allocate_to_len()` when, after incrementing len, `len >= cap`

i.e.

```
void append(...) {
    len += 1;
    if (len >= cap)
        allocate_to_len();
    ...
}
```

**Capacity Computation Loop is Unnecessary**

When computing the new capacity, you double the current capacity until it is greater than the current length. If you follow my above suggestion, then the capacity is guaranteed to be *at least* the length, if not larger. Doubling it once is enough, so the loop can be removed. Furthermore, you can also simply compute the new capacity as double the length. I believe this is the standard allocation behavior of `std::vector`

```
cap = len*2;
```

Is enough, barring ensuring that you haven't exceeded the maximum length as pointed out by another answer.

Overall great job! I'm just nitpicking. Rewriting standard containers and algorithms is incredibly helpful and something I did as well when I was first learning.